# Tensorflow 2 Object Detection API - Unable to run evaluation via model_main_tf2.py

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have recently moved from TF1 to TF2, when I have heard the amazing news that Object Detection API was migrated to the new version.
However, as soon as I have started using TF2, training and evaluation started to be very tiresome.
Below I have included some general issues that I have with the TF2 and the main problem that I need to tackle.

**General questions**

I'm using TF 2 OD API on my own data and preforming transfer training using different pre-trained models.
Here, already during the training, I can notice that the loss printed by the console is very irregular and jumps from very low numbers to very high values in a matter of 100-200 training steps ([Training logs image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5COW.png.))
Is this correct behaviour?

On top of that, in Tensorflow 1.x Object Detection, the evaluation was successfully performed while the training lasted. I could see both train images in the Tensorboard and the predictions with assigned classes.
In case of TF2, I can only spot training images, that are additionally this high-contrast/low-guality versions of themselves. [Link to the images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJ9W3.png)

I guess, this is after the data augmentation from the pipeline.config is applied (?).

For the training, I am running below code:

```
python object_detection/model_main_tf2.py \
--pipeline_config_path=${PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH} \
--model_dir=${MODEL_DIR} \
--alsologtostderr
--sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=2
```

During the training itself there are no evaluation metrics available. In TF 1.x, mAP@0.5IoU and other values were already visible during the execution of the training. In case of TF 2, I have tried to achieve any results for both coco and oid metrics by tuning specific setting in the config file but without any luck.

**Evaluation cannot be executed - TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType**

Nevertheless, the biggest issue comes when evaluation is executed. While running the code following below structure:

```
python object_detection/model_main_tf2.py \
--pipeline_config_path=${PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH} \
--model_dir=${MODEL_DIR} \
--checkpoint_dir=${CHECKPOINT_DIR} \
--alsologtostderr
```

After TF2 is started and initialized, latest checkpoint is read and then I receive below error code:

```
I0901 22:21:48.011265 49544 checkpoint_utils.py:134] Found new checkpoint at kodels/faster_rcnn_resnet50_v1_640x640_coco17_tpu-8_groceries\ckpt-30
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_main_tf2.py", line 113, in <module>
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\Mgr_TF2_P8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 40, in run
_run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\Mgr_TF2_P8\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\Mgr_TF2_P8\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "model_main_tf2.py", line 80, in main
    model_lib_v2.eval_continuously(
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\Mgr_TF2_P8\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 974, in eval_continuously
    os.path.join(model_dir, 'eval', eval_name))
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\Mgr_TF2_P8\lib\ntpath.py", line 78, in join
    path = os.fspath(path)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Could anyone advice on what could be the source of the issue? Is there any way to execute evaluation in TF 2 Object Detection API by using saved checkpoints?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the part from your config file which is responsible for data augmentation?

Comment: This is the whole "setting" for the model. I am using Faster RCNN Resnet 50 640x640          data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }

Comment: However, train images being visualized "differently" than in the TF 1.x seems to be behind the issue discussed [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/9115#issuecomment-677508264)

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: I am having the same issue, were you able to solve it ?